# Why there are so many typedef in linux source code?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Examples from types.h file from Linux source code

```
typedef __kernel_timer_t    timer_t;
typedef __kernel_key_t      key_t;
typedef __kernel_timer_t    timer_t;
```

They all are `typedef` of `int`(datatype). Linux contains so many `typedef` of simple datatype like `long`, `int` etc. Is there any specific reasons they have done that?

Answer (score 3):

Several factors come to mind:

- linux supports many different platforms and architectures and it might make sense that some data types be allowed to float to different sizes in those different environments -- for efficiency, say. The typedef then allows the fundamental type to vary on different architectures -- usually by including platform-specific headers.
- On the other hand, it may be necessary for some key data types that they actually be of specified lengths (for persistent/shared data structures or just to guarantee the range of values) but that might actually *require* them to be declared with different fundamental types on different architectures. (Note that with a few exceptions, the C language standard does not guarantee particular lengths for the various numeric types.)
- In order to build system call bindings, it must be possible to export many of the kernel's data type specifications to glibc (or other libc implementation) so that user space values can be reliably passed into system calls.
- A type called `key_t` (for example) in the kernel might already be in use for some other data type in user space code. Hence using `__kernel_key_t` allows the type to be distinct even where it may be needed in code that uses another notion of `key_t` without any ambiguity.

The additional layers of typedefs allow all these concerns to be handled while not unduly burdening kernel developers by making them type `__kernel_XXX_t` all the time.

Comment: I didn't get your answer. I think typedef is like nick name to the a datatype. I can only think one reason for so many typedef is that in linux the kernel runs by itself, without the help of the C library.so kernel functions needs to be mapped with c functions so that c programmers can work without knowing of  kernel functions.otherwise they have to use kernel function's name.                                                                     
please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: Yes, a typedef is like a nickname for the datatype. I gave several reasons why that's useful in my answer. But otherwise, you're wrong. The kernel does not "run by itself" -- it's useless to have a kernel without user space programs. User space code never accesses kernel functions by name. Mapping C functions to kernel entry points is done in the C library (libc); those functions are called 'system call wrappers' because they allow C programmers to use symbolic names to call into numbered entry points in the kernel. (All of that is orthogonal to typedefs though.)

Comment: There is also a historical aspect since in 199x not all modern types were available like, for example, `char_least16_t` (hipotetically needed in kernel). Ah, and one more — `kernel` prefix for the same / similar types which userspace is using but on purpose to distinguish that they are for kernel internal use only.